# Re-formatting a date in python

Tags: python

So I have a date in this format "August 10, 2022". I need to reformat the date in this way "2022-08-10". How do I do that in python ?.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), specifically on [this behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
from datetime import datetime 

a = "August 10, 2022"
b = datetime.strptime(a, '%B %d, %Y') # Converts to datetime format
c = b.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # Converts from datetime to desired format
print(c)
```

```
# output
2022-08-10
```